# Can we get debug packages in Launchpad?

Tags: package-management, launchpad

I see some project offering their `...-dbgsym.deb` packages on launchpad (see [ALSA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/hirsute/+source/alsa-lib)).

My projects, however, do not seem to generate those packages.

When I create packages on my machine, I do see those packages.

Could it be that it is turned off in my project?

Could there be an issue where the compiled version is pure release and thus the libraries anyway do not include any symbols and as a result not dbgsym package is created?

Answer (score 1):

Someone was kind enough to answer. It's available, but turned off by default.

For my project, I can find the two concerned flags on this page:

```
https://launchpad.net/~snapcpp/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+edit
```

Please make sure to change the project name (`snapcpp` here) before using the URL.

The flags are named:

- Build debug symbols, and
- Publish debug symbols

Just be careful since it's going to add more packages to your PPA repository and thus make it bigger. (a.k.a. you may run out of disk space) If you generate many different versions of each of your packages, this can grow quickly (i.e. AMD64, x86, ARM, etc.)

Although you can ask to increase the disk space, I don't think they do that for every single project. Also you can always remove older versions that you don't use anymore (that part is automatic within a distribution, but older distribution packages stick around for a while).